# How to save a message in mu4e as outlook compatible file?

Tags: mu4e

How can I save/export a message in a fileformat e.g. `.msg` in order to have coworkers open it with microsoft outlook?

At work we must use collaboration applications where we need to attach messages

Comment: In general you can't export to msg/pst as these are patented, proprietary formats, that Microsoft has declared as "open", and no one has really worked on utilities for them outside of Microsoft. You're better off export to a format that Outlook can import. Plain text (mbox) is always an option. If your co-workers double-clicking attachments to open in Outlook, there's not much difference to double-clicking and opening attachments in Notepad.

Comment: For bulk transfer/conversion, look into using an intermediary IMAP server.

Comment: Thank you @nega Could you please elaborate a bit on the mbox & mu4e combination? A brief search for *mu4e mbox export* did not return any point to start with.

Comment: You don't specifically _need_ mbox. mu (and hence, mu4e) use Maildir, which stores each individual message under a hierarchy of directories (usually under `~/Maildir`. If `mu4e` can't export directly to mbox, just use `mu4e`'s export, save or move command to save your message. `mu4e` has a pipe command, so you could use that to just `cat` your message to a file.

Comment: @nega Accepted answer, thank you. Can't upvote comments yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't export to msg/pst as these are patented, proprietary formats, that Microsoft has declared as "open", and no one has really worked on utilities for them outside of Microsoft. You're better off exporting to a format that Outlook can import. Plain text ([mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox), for example) is always an option. If your co-workers are double-clicking attachments to open in Outlook, there's not much difference to double-clicking and opening attachments in Notepad.

Note that you don't specifically need the mbox format. `mu` (and hence, `mu4e`) use [Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir), which stores each individual message in a separate file under a hierarchy of directories (usually under ~/Maildir.) If `mu4e` can't export directly to mbox, just use `mu4e`'s export, save or move command to save your message. `mu4e` has a pipe command, so you could use that to just cat your message to a file. Also note that `mu` (and `mu4e`), can strip/save attachments in messages to a separate file, if that's something you're after.